# Cannot deploy Spring, Struts 2, and Hibernate webapp due to startup errors

Tags: hibernate, spring, struts2

I have to introduce some changes in an app I didn't develop originally.

It uses Maven. When I try to deploy after doing a `mvn install`, I get the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor': 
Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] 
while setting bean property 'transactionInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' 
while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' 
defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
dameTipoRelacion, consultaPerfil, consultaOrganizacionPorPadre, obtenerDepartamentos, consultaOrganizacionPorPadreYNivel, 
consultaOrganizacionNivel, consultaGruposRelacion, consultaRelaciones, obtenerDepartamentosSC, dameGrupo, dameDepartamento
```

My persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="punit">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

If you need more config or source tell me.

Comment: have you defined any named queries?? since exception is occurring on persistence unit creation and it complaining about named queries??

Comment: Yep, there are defined, but I know that the app works. It's 100% functional, So I make a checkout and try to make some minors changes (that don't involve name queries...) So I think it's a problem with some configs or libraires... may it be?

Comment: log clearly indicating about named queries i don't think its has to be something with libraries since the exception are coming when it is trying to create "entityManagerFactory" and for its creation it is will only look for all mapping files defined inside cfg file or what ever name you have given to your main persistent mapping file

Answer (score 0):

The **error logs** are clear in this case,

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: dameTipoRelacion,.....
```

So, resolve this error, **dig in to all the named queries and verify that all your `named queries` are proper.**